# Creating PHP array from JSON output

Tags: php

Can anyone explain how can I insert the players from the JSON decoded output into a PHP array?

I'm using `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://website.com/url/api/'), true);`

The JSON output:

> [image: output]

My aim is to get the player names into an array and then use them in a foreach loop.

Comment: Have you tried `$data["players"]["sample"]`?

Comment: I'd loop over the `sample` array directly; you can also loop over `sample` to build your array; you can also check [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Realised right after hitting the post button!

Comment: you guys should put code the OP may not have much knowledge of php, you are right on the money though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://website.com/url/api/'), true);

$players = array();

foreach($data["players"]["sample"] as $player ){

     $players[] = $player['name'];

}
```

if you want to foreach them it's pointless building an array with foreach, as they should be an array already.  So you could just do whatever it is you want to do directly